# Google API fonts in a select box

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-font-api

https://stackoverflow.com/q/5065542/1716774
I like to apply the same function in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekdx/pJHnD/2/)

HTML

```
  <select id="styleFont">
          <option value="0">Myraid Pro</option>
          <option value="1">Sans ref</option>
          <option value="2">Times New Roman</option>
          <option value="3"> Arial</option>
 </select>
 <br>
  <textarea id="custom_text"></textarea>
```

CSS

```
 #custom_text{ resize: none;}​
```

Script

```
      $("#styleFont").change(function () {
     var id =$('#styleFont option' + ':selected').text();    
    $("#custom_text").css('font-family',id);
    });​
```

I tried to add the google API fonts in my select box by using

> https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=YOUR-API-KEY

how to add this to my fiddle

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13757196/adding-google-font-api-to-select-menu/57946077#57946077

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a JSONP request and add each returned font to a select:

```
function SetFonts(fonts) { 
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.items.length; i++) {      
     $('#styleFont')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value", fonts.items[i].family)
         .text(fonts.items[i].family));
    }    
}
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=API_KEY&callback=SetFonts';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Fonts API call returns JSON, so you would need JavaScript to iterate over the JSON result and populate the SELECT with it. Also, when the user selects one of the fonts, you would need to dynamically include the correct script from Google using the item the user has selected. [Read this part](https://developers.google.com/webfonts/docs/developer_api#Details) of the API docs for details on how to do that.

Comment: i have my API key which is https://www.googleapis.com/webfonts/v1/webfonts?key=AIzaSyB8Ua6XIfe-gqbkE8P3XL4spd0x8Ft7eWo. How can i link it  to my select box